What is the difference of WP and HOLD pin of a flash chip (Ex: W25Q128)
I don't really understand how Flash Chips works, my current understanding of these pins is that you must hold the HOLD pin to be able to communicate with the flash chip , but Write Protect seems to be similar , it must be hold high if you want to program the chip I think. If that's correct I do not understand the difference between the 2. Doesn't programming the chip mean writing on it ? If not then what, can the chip be programmed to run some program ?
Edit : The datasheet concerning the hold and WP pin
4.3 Write Protect (/WP)
The Write Protect (/WP) pin can be used to prevent the Status Register from being written. Used in
conjunction with the Status Register’s Block Protect (CMP, SEC, TB, BP2, BP1 and BP0) bits and Status
Register Protect (SRP) bits, a portion as small as a 4KB sector or the entire memory array can be
hardware protected. The /WP pin is active low.
4.4 HOLD (/HOLD)
The /HOLD pin allows the device to be paused while it is actively selected. When /HOLD is brought low,
while /CS is low, the DO pin will be at high impedance and signals on the DI and CLK pins will be ignored
(don’t care). When /HOLD is brought high, device operation can resume. The /HOLD function can be
useful when multiple devices are sharing the same SPI signals. The /HOLD pin is active low. When the
QE bit of Status Register-2 is set for Quad I/O, the /HOLD pin function is not available since this pin is
used for IO3. See Figure 1a-c for the pin configuration of Quad I/O operation.

Write protect prevents you from writing. It does not prevent reading, so it can be used to implement a read only memory.

@user1850479 , so HOLD when not held you can't even read, and when HOLD held but not WP it's read only, and if both you can then write and read ?

Hold probably disables communication with the chip entirely, but check the datasheet to see exactly how this is implemented.

@user1850479 , I copied a part of the datasheet in my question . But so if I want to always be able to read / write on the chip I just need to connect those two pins directly to Vddio (3.3v). Maybe with some resistors ?

Write Protect (/WP) is a hardware-level control that stops any SPI programme or erase commands from being carried out.
Such a function could be implemented in software but the /WP pin provides a simple higher level of reliability. Proving in test that software will not inadvertently carry out a programme or erase can be costly and time-consuming. Whereas a jumper and pull-down resistor that leaves /WP low when jumper unplugged is simpler to prove and so gives provable reliability at very low cost.
SPI Hold (/HOLD) can be used during SPI transfers to suspend the SPI transfer itself. The Flash EPROM (FEPROM) serial Data Out (DO) pin will be go high-impedance and the FEPROM will ignore changes on bus serial clock (SCLK) or Data Input (DI).
Hold is useful on an SPI bus that's connected to multiple SPI targets, with the FEPROM being only one of them. It allows the SPI bus to carry out an SPI transfer with another target right in the middle of an SPI transfer with the FEPROM.
Some examples of when you'd want to do this are:

So an ADC can still be read at a fixed interval.
To read from multiple FEPROMs at the fastest speed. All FEPROM /CS pin are asserted, the SPI read command is sent to them all simultaneously then all except one are kept in Hold while data is read from one FEPROM.

Since Hold was first added to SPI FEPROMS, other developments have sped up SPI, such as Quad SPI mode that transfers 4 bits per SCLK. And individual connections to the DO of multiple SPI FEPROMs would allow them to be read simultaneously. But the Hold function had a place in the market at one time.

Many applications don't need /WP and most don't use /HOLD. They can both be pulled HIGH through a suitable resistor.

Is the resistor really necessary ?

@Pablo, no, it's not electrically necessary. It does give you options if you might want to change it in the future. If it doesn't work or programme/erase, you'd want access to that pin which a PCB track to a pads-under-package IC might not give you. On a production line, ATE used to need to be able to change the pin level to test the IC, but that's not done so much now. So it's for you to trade off, whether to use resistors: part cost/stock/assy_reliability (downsides) vs test/dev access (upsides).

ok thanks , got it. What about their value ? 1ohm I suppose but I'd like to be sure.

You're welcome, @Pablo. Resistor value must be low enough for an insignificant voltage drop when they conduct the pin input leakage current, high enough to pass a tolerable current when shorted to GND for the earlier reasons. For a 3.3V IC then 10K would be a good choice.

Ok, I don't understand the 10k (if U=RI , I=U/R , I=3.3/10000=0.0003Amp , is that enough current ?) but still Thanks A LOT for your help.

@Pablo, it's fine but let's do this in one explanation, and you'll have to look info up to understand further. From W25Q128 datasheet 9.4, input leakage current ILI is +/-2 uA, min V for logic HIGH VIH is 0.7xVcc = 2.3 V. So resistor Vdrop must be less than 3.3-2.3 = 1 V when conducting 2 uA. R = V/I = 1/0.000002 = 500K max. So can allow a big margin. Hence 10K is fine, as is 100K. I'd use a value I'm using elsewhere on board, for min. pick/place component changes in manf. Read the datasheet, search internet for "logic input pull-up resistor calculations" etc. Glad it's a help, good luck :-)

Yea I'll do some searching on my own and try to understand this. Thanks Again
